# Difference between [^0-9] and [^0-9]+?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove all non-numerals from a string. Would there by any difference between these 2 lines of code:

```
re.sub('[^0-9]+', '', strr)

re.sub('[^0-9]', '', strr)
```

Comment: I don't think there's any difference for your particular case, they match different things but it makes no difference here.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I thought, but just needed to confirm. Thank you!

Comment: `[^0-9]` is a single character that is not a digit. `[^0-9]+` is more than one in a sequence. Since `re.sub` is global anyway, the result is the same. The *how it got there* might be different.

Answer (score 1):

“The +, known as occurrence indicator (or repetition operator), indicates one or more occurrences (1+) of the previous sub-expression. In this case, [0-9]+ matches one or more digits.” The ^ makes it not  any digit 0-9.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Since I am using it in the re.sub function trying to remove all non-numerics from a string, then the result of both functions would always be the same in this case, correct?

Comment: Yes from my understanding